# Entity Framework . Nested Collection Query passes Empty "value" on setter Method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a "Driver" model with one to many "Trucks" navigation property.
I want to Populate a sample "TruckDriver" model with a comma separated string property containing all related Truck Id's .

In order to populate this model seamlessly i have implemented a setter function which receives an Int32[] array and serializes it into a String.

The problem i am facing, is that while trying to populate this model with a single query using projection, linq to entities passes an empty collection to the setter "value" property .

Bizarrely if don't try to process the data, but only assign it as an IEnumerable it works fine .It works fine also if i instantiate my data first and then execute the query.

Example Code:

Model trying to populate.

```
public class TruckDriver
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Serialized { get { return this._serialized; } }
    public IEnumerable<Int32> OriginalArray { get; set; }  <--Debug Property to test actual data returned by the query.
    private String _serialized;
    public IEnumerable<Int32> setSerialized {
        set { 
            this._serialized = String.Join(",", value); <---- value is always an empty collection on the debugger
        } 
    }
}
```

Query Execution

```
        var temp = db.Drivers.Include(d=>d.Trucks);
         TruckDriver[] drivers=   temp.Select(d => new TruckDriver
            {
                Name= d.FirstName+" "+d.LastName,
                OriginalArray = d.Trucks.Select(r=>r.Id),
                setSerialized = d.Trucks.Select(r => r.Id),
            }).ToArray();
        return drivers;
```

Data Returned.

```
[{"Name":"Mark Miller","Serialized":"","OriginalArray":[1,4]},{"Name":"John Smith","Serialized":"","OriginalArray":[2,3]}]
```

As you see. "OriginalArray" and "setSerialized" get the exact same data. Although "OriginalArray" contains correctly a number of integers, "Serialized" is an empty string.

If i instantiate all data before executing the query, the model is populated correctly.

Instantiation before query.

```
        var temp = db.Drivers.Include(d=>d.Trucks).ToArray();
         TruckDriver[] drivers=   temp.Select(d => new TruckDriver
            {
                Name= d.FirstName+" "+d.LastName,
                OriginalArray = d.Trucks.Select(r=>r.Id),
                setSerialized = d.Trucks.Select(r => r.Id),
            }).ToArray();
```

Results

```
[{"Name":"Mark Miller","Serialized":"1,4","OriginalArray":[1,4]},{"Name":"John Smith","Serialized":"2,3","OriginalArray":[2,3]}]
```

Interesting thing to note is that if i write my own setter for the "OriginalArray" property , "value" is still an empty collection within the debugger during the "set" execution, although data is populated correctly afterwards.

```
public class TruckDriver
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Int32> OriginalArray 
    { 
        get{
            return this._originalArray;
        }
        set {
            this._originalArray = value; //<-- value is still an empty collection
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<Int32> _originalArray;

}
```

Result.

```
[{"Name":"Mark Miller","OriginalArray":[1,4]},{"Name":"John Smith","OriginalArray":[2,3]}]
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If your trying to do this all in the database,  I imagine Entity Framework has no idea how to translate the code in setSerialized to SQL.  It may work when instantiated first because that takes the setSerialized out of the database

Comment: setting the break point in the "value" property indicates an empty instance of an IEnumerable not a reference to an IQueryable. 
Even  manually instantiating the value using "value.ToArray();" returns also an empty array.

Comment: not sure if this will make any difference but what happens when you executed the ToArray() outside of setSerialized as in setSerialized = d.Trucks.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray()

Comment: that throws the exception "Linq to Entities does not recognize the medhod "ToArray()" because it can't translate it to sql

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get the `string.Join()` to happen in the database is not going to work because Linq does not know how to translate it SQL.  You could probably write a raw SQL query or stored procedure for it but I don't think youre gaining much with that.  You're basically going to have to pull it into memory first and then create the serialized string.  You could possible use a projection into an anonymous object to limit the data that you pull.

```
var temp = db.Drivers.Select(d => new 
{ 
    Name = d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName,
    TruckIds = d.Trucks.Select(t => t.Id)
}).ToArray();

var truckDrivers = temp.Select(d => new TruckDriver() 
{
    Name = d.Name,
    setSerialized = TruckIds
}
```

Comment: If you read the code carefully, i am not trying to execute String.Join within the database (I would get an exception otherwise). 
I am fetching the Int16[] into the memory and then trying to process these numbers inside the setter method, which executes after the data have been fetched.
Even if i don't try to join the numbers, and set a breakpoint within the setter, the Int16[] values are empty.
So it is mostly a Nested Query Collection mapping problem.